# Conditionally map data to build flat associative array while ignoring duplicated key with unwanted value

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements, mapping, associative-array

### Introduction

I have been working with arrays and I realize that PHP does not return duplicate keys.

I am working with a system that holds user's basic information, and when I query it, I get an object in this format:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [columnList] => Array
        (
            [0] => UID
            [1] => PIN
        )

    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 123456789
                [1] => SOME_RANDOM_USER_PIN
            )
    )
)
```

Now, I have created a simple function to filter and return a `key=>value` pair:

```
private function handle_obj( $array )
{
    // if it's an object we treat it as such
    if ( is_object( $array ) )
    {
        // reduce array->data to simpler format
        $call_data = array_reduce( $array->data, 'array_merge', [] );
        // trim array values
        $call_data = array_map ( 'trim', $call_data );

        // count each array and make sure they have the same number
        if ( count($array->columnList) == count( $call_data ) )
        {
            // combine both arrays
            $combine = array_combine ( $array->columnList, $call_data );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( count($array->data) > 0 )
            {
                foreach( $array->data as $column => $data )
                {
                    $combine[] = array_combine( $array->columnList, $data );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $combine = $array;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The result is:

```
$combine == array(
    'UID' => '123456789',
    'PIN' => 'SOME_RANDOM_USER_PIN'
);
```

#### Problem

The problem I currently have is that `UID` is listed twice, the first time it's in `plaintext`, however, the second time it comes to me in a encrypted string.

```
[118] => ����̅C�~J�U�V���;Z,o��l�L:�D�1�XO�%+⚃u���%V\�^b�   3���ԧ
```

The object would look something like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [columnList] => Array
        (
            [0] => UID
            [1] => PIN
            [2] => UID
        )

    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 123456789
                [1] => SOME_RANDOM_USER_PIN
                [2] => ����̅C�~J�U�V���;Z,o��l�L:�D�1�XO�%+⚃u���%V\�^b� 3���ԧ
            )
    )
)
```

The function `handle_obj` then would skip the first one and only return to me the second row.

Now, I am not concerned about the encrypted field, I only want the first one which comes with the plaintext.

I am trying to figure out how to modify the code I have to just a general script which will work no matter how the order of the items come back to me, I don't want to select a specific row only because this happens on others field too.

I need a way to compare both array items and pick the non-encrypted one.

Comment: It would probably help if you showed us an example of your array which also contained this data you want to ignore

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated my question

Comment: I am assuming this is fetched from a database query! Could you just NOT select the column with the UID you dont want to have to process

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, I am going through an API, they send the response as is, I can't pick which data I want to receive, I only choose the methods for what data I need. e.g. Address, Background, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure whether the "good" PIN will occur before the "bad" PIN, then make the stored PIN overwritable if it isn't `int` type.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9t5W9))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($obj->columnList as $i => $k) {
    if (!isset($result[$k]) || !is_int($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $obj->data[0][$i];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

If you are 100% sure that the good PIN will occur first, then don't make the value overwritable -- make the key "declarable" only once.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TRNcb))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($obj->columnList as $i => $k) {
    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $obj->data[0][$i];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```